# What is the equivalent of ScalaInstance.jars.classpath in sbt 1.3.3?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to move a scala project from sbt `1.2.7` to `1.3.3` and there are a lot of errors. One of them is

```
value jars is not a member of sbt.internal.inc.ScalaInstance
scalaInstance.map( _.jars.classpath).value
```

The `ScalaInstance` class can be found in `Zinc` repo and it does not have `jars` as a member in the latest master. What would be the equivalent code now?

Comment: As you can see in the package name, this is an `internal` API, so it shouldn't be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.allJars` instead.

I'm not sure if the `.classpath` extension method will work, so you might need to tweak that.